# To count dictionary lookup from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, count

A dictionary as below, showing the team members names of the month:

```
team_month = {
'TeamAAug' : ["William","Harper","Elijah","James"] ,
'TeamAOct' : ["William","Mason","Harper","Elijah","James"] ,
'TeamASep' : ["William","Mason","Elijah","James"] ,
'TeamBAug' : ["Mia","Emma","Charlotte","Sophia"] ,
'TeamBOct' : ["Mia","Sophia"] ,
'TeamBSep' : ["Emma","Charlotte","Sophia"]}
```

A dataframe as below to show each person if get bonus for the month:

[image]

I want to count for each team each month how many bonus. the ideal result should be like:

```
TeamAAug : 3
TeamAOct : 3
TeamASep : 0
TeamBAug : 2
TeamBOct : 1
TeamBSep : 0
```

What I can think of and tried:

```
import pandas as pd

team_month = {
'TeamAAug' : ["William","Harper","Elijah","James"] ,
'TeamAOct' : ["William","Mason","Harper","Elijah","James"] ,
'TeamASep' : ["William","Mason","Elijah","James"] ,
'TeamBAug' : ["Mia","Emma","Charlotte","Sophia"] ,
'TeamBOct' : ["Mia","Sophia"] ,
'TeamBSep' : ["Emma","Charlotte","Sophia"]}
    
data = {'Name': ["William","Mason","Harper","Elijah","James","Mia","Emma","Charlotte","Sophia",], 
'Aug' : ["Bonus","","Bonus","","Bonus","","Bonus","","Bonus",],
'Sep': ["","","","","","Bonus","","","",],
'Oct' : ["Bonus","","","Bonus","Bonus","","","","Bonus",]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

name_month_dict = df.set_index('Name').T.to_dict('dict')

for key, values in team_month.items():
        for v in values:
                print (v + key[-3:])
```

Above gives me a dictionary of each person's month bonus.

Output of "name_month_dict":

```
{'William': {'Aug': 'Bonus', 'Sep': '', 'Oct': 'Bonus'}, 'Mason': {'Aug': '', 'Sep': '', 'Oct': ''}, 'Harper': {'Aug': 'Bonus', 'Sep': '', 'Oct': ''}...}
```

And names with months:

```
WilliamAug
HarperAug
ElijahAug
…
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: Are all the names that are present in `team_month` dictionary are also present in `df` in the `Name` column?

Comment: @Shubham Sharma, thank you for the comment. Yes, they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try lookup using `loc` inside a `dict` comprehension:

```
l = df.set_index('Name') # lookup dataframe
{k: l.loc[v, k[-3:]].eq('Bonus').sum() for k, v in team_month.items()}
```

---

```
{'TeamAAug': 3,
 'TeamAOct': 3,
 'TeamASep': 0,
 'TeamBAug': 2,
 'TeamBOct': 1,
 'TeamBSep': 0}
```